# Style not being applied to newly installed themes

Tags: css

really hoping someone can help, I am at the end of my tether.. 
I have tried installing new themes and none of them have the style applied when i activate them, or even preview them for that matter. I have no idea what to do, I have tried searching for answers online but nothing makes sense or sounds familiar. The twentyseventeen theme still works, but that is the only one... I am on a local server at the moment and have two databases (sites) on it (not sure if that makes any difference). Sorry if this isnt specific enough but I dont know enough to say anything else about it and hoping for at least some direction.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the stylesheet are not linked properly.

If you are using Google Chrome, right-click and select **Inspect**. A new window with all kinds of code will show up. Find and expand the `<head>` element. There, you will find a long list of  elements. These are the stylesheets enqueued from a wide variety of sources. Check whether they have identifying ID or not.

If they haven't, then it's the cause of your problem.